# Dropbox 2-Step Authentication For iOS Application

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, dropbox-api

This is what I am trying to do. I am a little stuck and currently not sure what route to take. Please advise:

1. Create a XML file in a secured folder on Dropbox
2. Add 2-step authentication to read the XML file

Any directions will be helpful. Again this is a personal Dropbox where I am keeping the files. User doesn't have to know where the files are coming from.

Comment: What does "2-step authentication" mean here? What are the two steps?

Comment: @smarx He's referring to [2-Step Verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-step_verification).

Comment: Could be. "Two-factor authentication" and "Two-step verification" both refer to the same thing, but I haven't heard "2-step authentication". Even if 2FA is what he means, the question remains of what the two steps/factors would be.